# What SOLID principles does the observer pattern follow/violate?

Tags: observer-pattern, software-design, solid-principles

I'm studying for an exam and are currently reading about the observer pattern. Then I was wondering what SOLID principles the observer pattern follows or violates?

Comment: Why don't you take a stab at it and tell us what you think?

Answer (score 3):

Design patterns are - as their name implies - only patterns. Their actual implementation might highly differ among various applications.

In general, the most relevant SOLID principle related to Observer is the Open/Close Principle: Once you have written the code of the observed object, you need not change the code when you want additional observers to know it, yet it is easy to add such observers - this is exactly what "closed for modifications, open for extensions" mean.

It might also be considered an application of the Dependency Inversion Principle: The observed subject enforces a known API in which whoever wants to observe it must follow some rules, and in particular, the observed subject will call their `update()` function instead of calling the observers' specific functions. That way, if the observers are to be changed, the observed class has nothing to do (compare that to the option of calling a specific observer function).

In the basic, classical implementation (i.e., the one from GoF), there might be violations of SRP and ISP.

In that implementation, the object that is being changed is responsible for updating the observers. This is another responsibility that the class holds, in addition to its main responsibility. Thus, there is more then a single "reason" to update the class in the future - if the updating mechanism has to be changed (e.g. use a different container, use thread-safe mechanism, etc.) - the change will take place on the same class that has a completely different main responsibility. Of course, this can be solved by separating the "Observer" mechanism to another class.

Another possible SOLID violation by the simplistic implementation is that according to that implementation of the GoF, each updated observer should then inspect the status of the observed subject to detect a change. That might mean there is no interface segregation since any observer should be exposed to everything in the observed subject. However, it does not have to work that way, and it is very easy to provide a bit more sophisticated implementations that use different interfaces to different observers.

The pattern has not much to do with the Liskov Substitution Principle - as long as inheritance (e.g. inheriting the observer and the observed types by concrete types) does not do something they shouldn't, that principle will be kept.

Answer (score 1):

My own thoughts:

I think it follows OCP because you can extend the the code with new observers in the future rather than modifying existing code to make these new observers fit in.
It also follows ISP because the Subject and Observer interface is precise and small for the specific job that the observer/subject is meant to do.

It becomes a little far-fetched when I'm trying to make the rest of the principles fit into the observer pattern. And maybe the ISP is aswell? What are your thoughts? 
Software design patterns do not necessarily make use of all principles do they?